# How to create my own operations

Tags: stellar-core, operations

I'm looking to alter stellar-core for my project, which deals less with financial transactions and more with data storage. I want to essentally rip out some of the operations such as `allowTrust` and create operations of my own. Could someone give me a high level overview of what I should be looking at? So far it seems like I just need to alter the code under `/transactions` and `/xdr` but that seems too good to be true.